# Can I control commercially available zigbee switches and devices through my Xbee?

Tags: xbee, zigbee

Can I control commercially available zigbee switches and devices through my Xbee, that connects to my microcontroller?

I want to design home-automation where I would like to controll Lights, fans, AC, Curtains etc. from my board. Can I use Xbee S2 module to Connect to these Lights (As they are zigbee Switches)?

Comment: @AnindoGhosh There are much worse examples of English on this site. Please edit if bothers you.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh Sorry if that is bothering you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as they are zigbee alliance certified, in theory, yes you can. That is what zigbee alliance is there for. But you will have to dig deep into documents of those switches first. Without documents from specific switches, I don't think we can help you further.

Comment: I just wanted to be sure , so that I can then know wether the manuals that they will provide will help me or should I just change Xbee with some other device etc